# How to call Blob Images as Rest Services

Tags: oracle, rest, web-services, oracle-apex

i have my Blob Images store in Oracle Database. i want to create a Get Methode to retrieve it as JSON Format.

That is the Structure of my DB
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it working fine now. i Just write it as sql Query and create the Rest 
[image]